# I can't use PERCENTILE_DISC and PERCENTILE_CONT in MySQL, getting some error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using PERCENTILE_DISC() window function in mysql , but getting an error , don't know why, but this same query working fine on my friend's mysql workbench

error -->

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '(ORDER BY Price) OVER() FROM drug_clean' at line 1

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY Price) OVER()
FROM drug_clean
```

I am expecting to get 50 percentile value or median for price column, but getting an error

Comment: Mysql has no such functions - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html 'but this same query working fine on my friend's mysql workbench' - is it? or is he/she using mariadb which does have this function? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/percentile_disc/ Please publish the result of select version() and check version to link

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Percentile_Disc doesn't work even as a window function in MySQL server, so you have to download MariaDB server (https://mariadb.org/download/?t=mariadb&p=mariadb&r=11.2.0&os=windows&cpu=x86_64&pkg=msi&m=aliyun) from this link you can download.

After installing MariaDB

Open Workbench and

Right click on your default database

Go to edit connection

THERE YOU WILL SEE 3 TABS (parameter, SSL, Advance)

GO to Advance

Go to Others Box

There write these following 2 things:

1. serverVersion=11.2MariaDB (Write the version of MariaDB server installed in your pc)
2. useSSL=0

PS: If you have installed MySQL server already then while installing MariaDB
you will be asked to type a new port name (which is by default 3306 for local computer). I don't know if you could write any number like 3307 or 3308, but what I did was that I deleted MySQL server first and then installed MariaDB server.